# Azure IoThub end point creation using ARM template?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-iot-hub

Can someone please suggest how to create iothub endpoint which is compatible with event hub using ARM template? I am not able to generate the connection string in ARM template for the creation of endpoint dynamically?

Comment: Have you referred to the sample [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-rm-template-powershell)? In this tutorial, it creates two consumer groups (cg1 and cg2) on the Event Hub-compatible endpoint.

Comment: Yes, it creates the consumer group, but not the end point. I am looking for creating the end point in IoTHub, once the end point is created I will have to create the routing logic for the end point. So far I was able to do all the activities except the dynamic URL creation for the IotHub end point.

Comment: You need not to generate the connection string in ARM template dynamically.In fact, you can get the endpoint from the provisioned IoT Hub within the ARM template.

Comment: Michael, I'm facing a similar problem. Can you elaborate on how one ought to do this?

Comment: We could not do it with ARM template, we manually added routing details once basic IoTHub is created using ARM template. I know this can be done using powershell as well. Please share if someone is able to get a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lately we are able to find a solution. First thing we did was combined both iothub and eventhub templates. Then dynamically get the event hub end point details while creating iothub. Here is the snippet worked

"variables": {
    // event hub access policy name
    "eventHubAccessPolicy": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Eventhub/namespaces/EventHubs/AuthorizationRules', 
parameters('eventHubNS'), 
parameters('eventHubName'),parameters('sharedAccessPolicyName'))]"
  },
  .
  .
  .
  //while creating iothub add below end point and route.
 "routing": {
  "endpoints": {
    "eventHubs": [
      {
        **"connectionString": "[listKeys(variables('eventHubAccessPolicy'), '2017-04-01').primaryConnectionString]",**
        "name": "[parameters('eventHubName')]",
        "resourceGroup": "[resourceGroup().location]"
       }
    ]
  },
  .
  .
  .
  "routes": [
    {
      "name": "[parameters('routingName')]",
      "source": "DeviceMessages",
      "condition": "message='telemetric'",
      "endpointNames": [
        "[parameters('eventHubName')]"
      ],
      "isEnabled": true
     }
  ]
},

Answer (score 1):

Well,

It seems the answer is not complete (and also partly incorrect).

In the event hub endpoint node `"resourceGroup": "[resourceGroup().location]"` location has to be replaced by name `([resourceGroup().name]`.

Furthermore you need to add `"subscriptionId": "[subscription().subscriptionId]"` to the endpoint node. Otherwise the endpoint will be added without errors, but in the portal won't work (you can't open the properties of the endpoint when clicking on it - you get a 404).

And lastly - in the portal - when you create an endpoint - the authorization rule that is necessary for it, will be created automatically.

That won't happen when you define the routes and endpoints in an ARM template. You need to add the authorization rule to the Event Hub itself in the ARM template.
(how to do that, for instance see: https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/301-eventHub-create-authrule-namespace-and-eventHub)